# Using the concept of the binomial expansion solve: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I really have trouble starting these. Usually once I've begun I'm ok, but any help starting would be most appreciated.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{n}{k} $$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k+1}\dbinom{n}{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k+1}\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} = \dfrac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dbinom{n+1}{k+1} = \ldots$

Comment: See also [How can I compute $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1} {k + 1}\binom{n}{k} $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66118)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider the derivative of

$$\sum_{k=0} ^n
\frac  1{k+1}\binom nk X^{k+1}
$$
details:

$$f(X) = 
\sum_{k=0} ^n
\frac  1{k+1}\binom nk X^{k+1}\\
f'(X) = 
\sum_{k=0} ^n
\binom nk X^{k} = (1+X)^n\implies f(X) =  \frac1{n+1}(1+X)^{n+1}
\\
\sum_{k=0} ^n
\frac  1{k+1}\binom nk  = f(1)-f(0) = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
$$

---

Another way:
$$\frac  1{k+1}\binom nk X^{k+1}
= \frac {n!}{(n-k)! (k+1)!} = \frac1{n+1}\frac {(n+1)!}{(n-k)! (k+1)!} 
= \frac1{n+1} \binom {n+1}{k+1}
$$

Then, $$\sum_{k=0} ^n
\frac  1{k+1}\binom nk =\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0} ^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}
= \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
$$

Comment: error at the end fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
$$
\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k+1)!} = \frac{n!}{[(n+1)-(k+1)]!(k+1)!}
$$
Try to express this using binomial coefficients.

Comment: How do you propose to manipulate your rightmost term? Are you trying to do something different from Oleg's hint?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think Oleg is doing in his comment exactly what I was trying to make the OP do here. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$(1+x)^n=\displaystyle\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+....+\binom{n}{n}x^n$

and

$\displaystyle\int{y^n}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}y^{n+1}+C$

> $\displaystyle\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C=\displaystyle\binom{n}{0}x+\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{1}x^2+\frac{1}{3}\binom{n}{2}x^3+....+\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n}{n}x^{n+1}$