# Using binomial theorem to evaluate summation $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \binom nk$ in closed form

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

A problem I'm trying to figure out asks that I use the binomial theorem (or any other method I want) to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} {n \choose k}$ in closed form.

The binomial theorem stated in my textbook: $(1+x)^n = {n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}x+{n\choose 2}x^2+...+{n\choose k}x^k+...+{n\choose n}x^n$

I think the idea behind evaluating the summation to closed form is to perform some manipulation on the binomial theorem until it basically looks like what I want. My textbook only gives simplistic examples, like showing that $ \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$ by setting $x=1$. This doesn't really give me a good sense of how to do this problem.

Could I please have a hint?

Comment: Integrate, and see what happens.

Comment: OK, this has gotten me really close to the answer's below. I'm trying to remember how integration works (haven't done any math in a long time), I'm trying to figure out why the constant from integrating = -1

Comment: See also [How can I compute $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1} {k + 1}\binom{n}{k} $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66118)

Answer (score 6):

Lucian's comment is perfectly fine. As an alternative, a nice old trick:
$$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k+1}{n \choose k}}&
=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\
\overbrace{\pars{\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\,\dd t}}
^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{1 \over k + 1}}}\ =\ 
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}t^{k}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + t}^{n}\,\dd t =
\left.{\pars{1 + t}^{n + 1} \over n + 1}
\right\vert_{\, t\ =\ 0}^{\, t\ =\ 1}
\\[3mm] & =
{\pars{1 + 1}^{n + 1} - \pars{1 + 0}^{n + 1} \over n + 1}\
=\
\bbox[15px,border:1px solid navy]{\color{#44f}{\large{2^{n + 1} - 1 \over n + 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: This raises a few questions. I guess I'll start with just this one why integrate t^k over 0 to 1?

Comment: The choice of those limits allows you to set up the series that you want to sum.

Comment: I can see that by integrating over 0 to 1, I get end up with the result I want (one that's consistent with all the different methods for getting the desired closed-form), but I don't understand how the numbers 0 and 1 in particular, have anything to do with the original series

Comment: The integration in $\left(\,0,1\,\right)$ let's to introduce a well known result. Namely,$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}t^{k} = \left(\,1 + t\,\right)^{n}$. In many situations, it's easier to reduce the series to an integral. I saw $\color{#00f}{\tt @Sherlock Holmes}$ already pointed out this fact.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(-1+\binom{n+1}{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(-1+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n+1}(-1+2^{n+1})=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$