# Prove the summation of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to show that:

$\sum^{n}_{i = 0}$$n \choose i$$(i+1)^{-1}$ = $2^{n + 1}(n + 1)^{-1}$

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I have been trying expanding the binomial coefficient but with no luck @RiverX15

Comment: Start with $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^i$ and integrate it $\int_{0}^{1}$. When you integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\binom{n}{i}x^n=\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}\binom{n}{i}|_{0}^{1}=\binom{n}{i}(i+1)^{-1}$. So, in the right you get your sum.

Comment: The equation is not true, but see my answer for the correct RHS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using binomial theorem to evaluate summation $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \binom nk$ in closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940419/using-binomial-theorem-to-evaluate-summation-sum-k-0n-frac1k1-binom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\frac{1}{i+1} 
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n+1}{i+1}\frac{1}{n+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n+1}{i+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{i} - \binom{n+1}{0}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \left(2^{n+1} - 1\right) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful