# Binomial Theorem Sum

Tags: binomial-theorem

How would I find the sum below?

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{1}{k+1} {n \choose k}}=?$$

I need help starting on the problem. Would I first need to utilize the Binomial Theorem proof to get started on it?

Thank you.

Comment: How about simplifying the problem by picking numbers for $n$ and $k$? Can you work it out for, say $n=7$ and $k=3$ and let $k$ run from $0$ to $7$? Then can you generalize it if you observe where the $7$ and $3$ are "going to" ?

Comment: See also: [How can I compute $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{1} {k + 1}\binom{n}{k} $?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66118)

Answer (score 4):

We know that for any value of $x$:

(1) $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k$$

If we integrate both sides we get that:

(2) $$\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1} 
+ C = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

where $C$ is some constant.

Now to find the constant $C$ we put e.g. $x=0$ into (2).

So we get:

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + C = 0$$
$$C = -\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Now we put the found value of $C$ back into (2) and we get:

(3) $$ \frac{(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

Finally we put $x=1$ into (3) and we get the answer we were looking for:

(4) $$ \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: So I got(1/(x^(k+1))*((x+1)^(n+1))/(n+1))= sum of (n choose k) * (1/k+1) from k =0 to n. But I am not sure where to go from here. What do you mean choose carefully x?

Comment: This implication is not true. What follows is that RHS and LHS (after the integration) differ by a constant. To find what the constant is we can calculate e.g. RHS(0) and LHS(0).

Comment: @peter.petrov Thank you, that is true, yet this development is more used for power series where there's no need for that. I'm sure the asker can cover this, or if after he reads your comment he has some doubt he can ask.

Comment: @peter.petrov, The answer is (2^(n+1)-1)/(n+1), but I do not understand how to simplify up to that?

Comment: @SaiN Substitute $\;x=1\;$ in the above, and you get $\;\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} ...\;$ . I can't see where  the minus one in the numerator comes from in what you say is "the answer", but it could be adding a constant as peter commented.

Comment: @Joanpemo No offense but if you don't see where the minus one in the numerator comes from you didn't quite understand your own answer. I've modified the answer so that it's now obvious.

Comment: @peter.petrov Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @peter.petrov I think it is you that didn't understand as in my comment exactly above yours I explain the asker about the constant. Now, you gave the whole thing to him and that's fine: it is now obvious **to him** . Some people here downvote complete and detailed answers (I still cannot understand why but it's a fact) . I shall ponder whether to let untouched your edit to my answer or roll back later..

Comment: @SaiN Any time, it was a pleasure.

Comment: @Joanpemo Oh, OK, sorry, I thought you didn't understand it because you said: "I can't see where the minus one in the numerator comes from". So OK... good... we now all understand this, including the OP which is most important. I didn't know this thing about downvoting detailed answers. Btw, I don't think it's generally true. I would have posted this as my answer but the question was locked and still is.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Start by proving that

$$(n+1)\binom{n}k=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}\;;$$

this can be done quite easily either algebraically or combinatorially. Then rewrite this identity in a way that lets you simplify $\frac1{k+1}\binom{n}k$ usefully. You don’t really need the binomial theorem at all.

Comment: I am confused on what basis you said the above two equations are equal?

Comment: Oh nevermind, that's an identity. Thank you!

Comment: @SaiN: You’re welcome!